# How to override alt-codes in Windows?

Tags: windows, keyboard-shortcuts, alt-key

I'm trying to use <kbd>ALT + 0176</kbd> to get degree sign (°).

But when I use <kbd>ALT + Num 7/Home</kbd>, I am redirected to the browser homepage.

Comment: What do you mean, when you use it? When you key it in while on a website? Or your code is redirecting?

Comment: this is probably a [SuperUser](https://superuser.com) question. not for SO

Comment: Just html form. I'm trying to write degree sign in any textarea or input. As a result, I am redirected to the browser homepage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you are using a laptop that has a numpad.

The alt characters I believe need to be executed on a numpad and not the normal querty number row therefor you need to enable number lock.  In order to access those number keys, you need to ensure <kbd>Num Lk</kbd> is toggled on.

The <kbd>Num Lk</kbd> key should remove the default binding for <kbd>Home</kbd> and replace it with <kbd>Num7</kbd>

Comment: Thanks much! But is there any way to override any alt-code (for example, alt+home), when it is used within textarea, or input?

Comment: that's completely dependent on the keyboard in question.  I don't believe there's anything you could / should do in your code in order to subvert how keyboards work.